# Add column with initial value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Is it possible to set initial value for newly added column from another joined table?
Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE atable ADD COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
VALUE SELECT acolumn FROM something s WHERE s.id = atable.some_id
```

?

Comment: Is it 'SELECT acolumn' or 'SELECT mycolumn'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alter table using sub select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805179/alter-table-using-sub-select)

Comment: @Edper SELECT something from another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible.  Instead, use a separate `update` command:

```
ALTER TABLE atable ADD COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(255);

update atable a join
       something s
       on s.id = a.some_id
    set a.mycolumn = s.acolumn;
```

Comment: In addition, alter the column so that it becomes not null