# Stored Procedure to read text file and loop through it

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tried looking through a lot of threads on this but couldn't find anything that works for me.

I have a text file with list of table names (about 100 out of 300 total tables in the schema).

tables.txt

```
table1
table2
table3
```

I am writing a stored procedure and want to loop through the table names in that text file and inject the table names in the query.

Something like this

```
While (line = readline) != null do
 update line set col1='foo' where id=x;
End while;
```

Is something like that even possible in a stored procedure? using (mysql 5.6). and I am using Workbench 6.3 CE

Comment: In general, SQL syntax is optimized to work on sets rather than loops. (a group of data rather than a row at a time) You may find an answer quicker to look for a set based solution.

Comment: Is there one table name per line?

Comment: Yes, one table name per line in the file.

Comment: SQL is for querying databases not for reading text files

Comment: @DanSorensen how can I set the list of tables in a stored proc? I am open to try that if it works. It's fairly small table and one time script so I am not so worried about best practices or performances

Comment: @ElhamKohestani I want to ALTER around 100 tables with a same ALTER statement. So if not via a text file input, can I use some sort of array/list in the loop?

Comment: I posted and updated the answer.

Comment: Did you check the answer? Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you  want to run the same code for every table in your database.You can create your command using Information Schema

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT 
CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` ALTERING CODE HERE;") 
AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_schema_goes_here";
```

When the commands are created then you can copy and run all of them.

**UPDATE** If you want to update a column common between all those tables you can write it as follow

```
SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` SET COLUMN_NAME = VALUE [ANY WHERE CLAUSE]") as MySQLCMD from TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = "YourSchemaName";
```

**UPDATE2** Generating commands for specific tables.

```
   SELECT 
    CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` ALTERING CODE HERE;") 
    AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_schema_goes_here" AND TABLE_NAME IN ('Table1', 'TAble2');
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow this one. Does this go in the stored procedure? And the problem is I want to run about 100 out of a thousand tables from a schema.

Comment: This will create the commands(your table names injected inside them) then you can copy all those commands and run them at one time.

Comment: And if you want to run the same Update command you can do it too.

Comment: How does your query know which tables need ALTER'd out of all the tables in the schema? Do I run that in a stored proc or as a mysql query separately?

Comment: You can add a where clause Like TABLES.tableName IN(Specific tables)

Comment: If you need to run them many times so wrap them in a stored procedure but if you need them once then only run them as a separate query.

Comment: If you follow my steps 1-3, to import and parse the text file, you could then use this UPDATE 2 and use a subselect at the end to get the table names something like: TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT Table_Name FROM MyTempTABLE)

Comment: Elham, Update 2 worked! I was trying unnecessarily to make it more dynamic and automated in stored procedure. I had to give up and use your idea. Thanks much sir!

Answer (score 0):

In general I would take this approach. There is not enough detail to be more specific. Note, this uses dynamic SQL rather than a stored procedure.

1. Backup your database!!
2. Create a temporary table. (either real or in memory depending on how long you need this data retained)
3. Parse the text file into a temporary table using something like this:

   LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/mylist.txt' INTO TABLE MyTempList;
4. Create a test a single ALTER table statement. Once you know it works exactly as intended...
5. Convert your working ALTER statement into dynamic SQL that selects the table names from your temporary table. Something like this: [Alter table using sub select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805257/177260)
6. When complete, you can delete your temporary table.

Alternately, you could put a single ALTER statement into a stored procedure, asking for the table name as a parameter. But then you will still need to parse the text file using something like steps 1-3. And then use a cursor to loop over the table names and call the stored procedure.